# I want to set some value to storage.sync in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage

Im the options.js file I want to first generate a random number (this works) but then capture this random number to chrome.storage.sync.set to utilise later. I'd like to save the generated number in chrome.storage.sync.set when the user clicks on the 'save' button - which has the id 'formsave'.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (function() {
        var randomString = function(length) {

            var text = "";

            var possible = "0123456789";

            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

            }

            return text;
        }

        // random string length
        var random = randomString(10);

        // insert random string to the field
        var elem = document.getElementById("userid").value = random;

    }));

function save_userid() {
    var userid = document.getElementById('userid').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        theUserid: userid
    }
    )
};
document.getElementById('formsave').addEventListener('click',
save_userid);
```

The code I have currently reports the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: 1) DOMContentLoaded listener should be added on `document`, not `window`. 2) move the last line (that starts with document.getElementById) inside the first function.

Comment: Inside the function above it or the document.domcontentloaded function?

Comment: There's no need to ask me, why don't you try both? :-)

Comment: I've tried a bit further, no error messages as it is but still not completely certain it works

Comment: You can use devtools to set breakpoints and debug your code to make sure it works.